# Definir la posición de una ImageView en Java Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Es algo que no se como preguntarle a gooogle, lo que quiero es algo simple, se que en layout se puede definir la posición y el tamaño de un Button o TextView, también de una ImageView, pero lo que quiero hacer es definir la posición con código java, lo que se hasta ahora es cambiar la imagen, así:

```
    **Imagen= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImagenEditar);
    Imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.roca);**
```

Pero me gustaría saber el comando para definir la posición de la imagen(Con coordenadas, por ejemplo 50 en Y y 50 en X), gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes definir la posición al cargar en el layout, las posiciones no se toman relativas a un eje X/Y, se toman **Left** que es de izquierda a derecha en pixeles y **top** de arriba hacia abajo en pixeles, este es un ejemplo 
con `leftMargin` = 100 y `topMargin` = 100:

```
    // se toma la referencia de tu layout padre.
    RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);
    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    //Carga imagen de recursos
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android);
    imageview.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

    params.leftMargin = 100; //pixeles de derecha a izquierda.
    params.topMargin = 100; //pixeles de arriba a bajo.
    layout.addView(imageview, params);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambiamos a `leftMargin` = 300 y `topMargin` = 650:

```
    // se toma la referencia de tu layout padre.
    RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);
    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    //Carga imagen de recursos
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android);
    imageview.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

    params.leftMargin = 300; //pixeles de derecha a izquierda.
    params.topMargin = 650; //pixeles de arriba a bajo.
    layout.addView(imageview, params);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

prueba con `image.setLocation(new Point(50, 50));` donde `50,50` son `X` e `Y`